# Change connection string dynamically in ASP.net using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have two Button controls fetching data from two different databases using Entity Framework.

I want to change the connection string dynamically on both buttons' click events to get result using same query.

Something like:

```
DataTable dt;

private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetData();
}

private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetData();
}

private DataTable GetData()
{
    using (var context = new DB())
    {
        dt = context.Table1.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just have two separate connection strings and instantiate your context with one or the other as needed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18429993/1347784

Answer (score 0):

The `System.Data.Entity.DbContext` class (part of the EntityFramework assembly, NOT `System.Data.Entity` as you'd expect !!!) can be initialized with either a connection name or a connection string.

```
var context = new DbContext(myConnectionString);
```